# Amazon S3 Key does not exist

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am facing issue with Files having special characters like - ()
I installed S3 browser to see what path it is making and for file - `IDN_PreFetch_CM_(10.17.18).xlsx` , in S3 browser i see complete path as

```
Supporting Documents/SUP000011/MER-30DFNVR08V0-0001/Prefetch/Prefetch_10112018/IDN_PreFetch_CM_%2810.17.18%29.xlsx
```

In my C# code i also made path as - (which look exactly same)

```
Supporting Documents/SUP000011/MER-30DFNVR08V0-0001/Prefetch/Prefetch_10112018/IDN_PreFetch_CM_%2810.17.18%29.xlsx
```

But it does not work and say key does not exist , if i try another file under same path like (abc.xlsx) it works fine.

What else can be looked ?

Comment: () are allowed in key names: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: In S3 Browser it looks like - IDN_PreFetch_CM_%2810.17.18%29.xlsx for this filename - IDN_PreFetch_CM_(10.17.18).xlsx

Comment: _In S3 Browser it looks like_ are you sure you're seeing the actual path, rather than an escaped version?

Comment: Its quite weird..when i pass path as IDN_PreFetch_CM_(10.17.18).xlsx it gives error as "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details" but when i use escape version that is "IDN_PreFetch_CM_%2810.17.18%29.xlsx" , it says Key does not exist. I am pretty sure that there is some change that need to be made to filename because abc.xlsx works absolutely fine on the same path.

Comment: so next step: does abc().xlsx work?

Comment: It does not work and gives error - "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details."

Comment: And abc%28%29 gives key does not exist

Comment: Not sure about the C# sdk, but with the CLI, you must specify the `--recursive` option to copy all the contents under a key